# When did "stack" became synonymous with an instance of an effect? e.g. "Three stacks of vulnerability"

Tags: terminology

This might be a bit of a crossover question with linguistics. "Stacking" itself is a rather old concept, but referring to instances of buff/debuff as a "stack" seems to have appeared later.

Comment: It probably came from tabletop RPGs terminology, I found some early 2000s DnD threads using "stack" to define building up effects.